# Why do I need to remove a part of the insulation on a copper wire on a simple electric motor?

Tags: motor, coil, electromagnet

Why do I need to remove a part of the insulation on one end of a copper wire in making a simple coil electric motor?

How does removing only a part of the insulator makes the motor spin freely?

[Reference](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-a-Simple-Motor/) at step 3.

I know why the coil spins. What I'm confused on is: If I insulate only a part of end of the wire, wouldn't it stop getting electric current so it wouldn't spin anymore, or is it because of the momentum where a second of not getting current doesn't affect it's spin to continue the cycle?

[image: Simple copper coil electric motor]

Comment: Neat! I've not seen a 'half-wave' motor before.

Comment: Commutation at the bare essentials.

Comment: This could fail by the insulation on the other half being worn... OTOH, this might self heal by the formerly bare portion oxidizing enough just in time :)

Comment: accidential commutation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> *I know why the coil spins what I'm confused of is: If I insulate only
> a part of end of the wire, wouldn't it stops getting electric current?
> so it wouldn't spin anymore. or is it because of the momentum where a
> second of not getting current doesn't affect it's spin to continue the
> cycle?*

Removing half the circumferential insulation from the coil's trailing wire ensures that current conduction is prevented over 180° of the coils rotation. The object here is that it is indeed momentum that then carries the coil through the remaining 180°. If you didn't do this, the coil would want to remain aligned in one direction and wouldn't spin.

But it's important to remove the correct 180°; look at the picture very carefully and make sure you remove the insulation section corresponding with the coil in the vertical orientation shown: -

[image]

If you held the coils flat you'd be removing the wrong 180° portion of insulation. It's easy to fix by twisting the wire ends though. Maybe this picture (for a two plate commulator) does a better job at describing what I said: -

[image]

Image [from here](http://sph3u1-0.blogspot.com/2013/06/jun-10-class-dc-motor-and-induction.html).

As precisely shown in the picture, when a battery is applied, the armature will want to rotate 90° to align the magnetic field of the coil with the magnet. This creates the torque that causes the initial spin. As soon as it is close to alignment, you want the current to stop hence, the commutation (shown in the diagram immediately above) does this. OK, this is a more sophisticated commutation method that then reverses the current and drives the coil to rotate the next 180° but, in principle it's the same for your motor except your method uses momentum to carry it through the period when current is interrupted.